# Why is the derivative of sqrt(x) visualized like this?

Tags: calculus

[image: visualization]
[image: visualization]

I am having trouble reasoning out in my head why the derivative of sqrt(x) is depicted like this in this 3blue1brown video. In  the x^2 visualization I can easily understand why the dimensions of increase are x and x but for the sqrt(x) derivative intuitively I would think that the center of the square should be sqrt(x) and the sides would be something else I would not expect the sides to be both sqrt(x).

Comment: It's because the square root problem is given a square of area $x$ find the length of the sides which will be $\sqrt{x}$. If you write $y=x^2$ and substitute into the bottom square you can see it's identical to the first.

Comment: Why would the middle not be sqrt(x) ?

Comment: The square is a square, so it represents the squared quantity. The length of one side of the square is the square root of that square. Note that the square root was defined long before we had algebra or even arithmetic. The picture he's drawn is what is the definition of the square root is.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhh it just clicked in my head specifically the part where you said it is the defenition of a square root. That put it into perspective thx a lot bro.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I understand why it is written the way it is but I am a bit confused one how I should get 1/2sqrt(x) as the derivative from the visual. The x^2 visual is understandable because as the change gets smaller it approaches sides of the square that are each x long so 2x makes sense. But for the sqrt(x) visual sqrt(x) doesnt behave like x^2 so I am having trouble understanding why you add the sqrt(x) side together and then put them under 1. I under stand that the function is increasing at a decreasing rate I am just trying to piece together the logic from the visual alone.

Comment: That diagram is sort of backwards, since the area $x$ is the variable instead of being the function. However it's nearly identical to the square case but you're looking at how $dx$ compares to $d\sqrt{x}$ instead of how $x^2$ compares to $x$. You still get $dx = 2\sqrt{x}d\sqrt{x}$ but this time we're solving for $\frac{d\sqrt{x}}{dx}$ which gives us $\frac{d\sqrt{x}}{dx} = \frac1{2\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: I understand now that since sqrt(x) is increasing at a decreasing rate to describe the rate of change you need something that is decreasing at a decreasing rate and doing 1/sqrt(x) does that I am just intuitivly trying to figure out why double the rate now ?

Comment: For the same reason we get a $2$ in $2x$, there are two rectangles with non-trivial areas. Since you're trying to find the side length of exactly one of them you need to divide by $2$.

Comment: when dx gets smaller in the x^2 example I can picture the two rectangles getting so thin the equal 2x but for the sqrt x example the rectangles getting thiner reperesent how 2 of sqrt(x) are changing not just sqrt(x) ? sorry if I am sounding redundant just trying to rap my head around this

Comment: Yeah there are two of them so you have to account for that.