# How does this visual lead to an understanding of the derivative of sqrt(x)?

Tags: calculus

[image]

I am confused about how this visual will lead me to understand the derrivative of sqrt(x)? If sqrt(x) is increasing at a decreasing rate then why would I need to do 1/2sqrt(x) as the derrivative why would it just be 1/sqrt(x). I can prove this algebraically but I am just trying to visually picture what happnes when I put something under 1 and how that will lead me to neeeding to multiply sqrt(x) by 2 then putting it under 1 to get the correct answer ?

Comment: Related to [Why is the derivative of sqrt(x) visualized like this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4845277/89922)

Answer (score 1):

From the picture, the new area after adjusting the dimensions is
$$(\sqrt{x}+d\sqrt{x})^2 = x+2\sqrt{x}d\sqrt{x} + (d\sqrt{x})^2.$$
Therefore, the difference in area is
$$dx = x+2\sqrt{x}d\sqrt{x} + (d\sqrt{x})^2 - x = 2\sqrt{x}d\sqrt{x} + (d\sqrt{x})^2.$$
The derivative is
$$\frac{d\sqrt{x}}{dx} = \frac{d\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}d\sqrt{x} + (d\sqrt{x})^2}.$$
Now, take the limit of this expression as $d\sqrt{x} \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I understand the proof part I am just trying to figure out visually without the proof how is it possible form the diagram for me to know how to get the derivative geometrically without the algebra ?